# Can we override inventory check in BigCommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I want customers to order the product even if it is out of stock, however I want to keep the Inventory tracking option ON as well. So for example if I have a product with 100 items in the stock, if someone orders it I need to see how much left in the inventory and on the other hand of product is out of stock, customer should still be able to order it. Is there a way we can achieve this while overriding any API?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible :-( Possible hacky workaround could be to set inventory level to 1100 if you have 100 products in stock. Anything under 1000 would be technically out-of-stock, but would still allow customer to order the item.

Answer (score 0):

We got it to work by using ajax and javascript. Basically we replaced the text that is generated by bigcommerce for inventory with a little script that checks inventory through our ERP. We then turned off inventory tracking for all products and backorders are now available. I wish I could post a few lines of code to help you, but the script is specific to our database. You can still use all the other features of the API (order import etc.), but you are not using the api for inventory tracking.

Hopefully this gets the wheels turning.